# What is the difference between HttpContext.Current.Application.Get([some enum]) and just enum?

Tags: c#, httpcontext

I have:

```
HttpContext.Current.Application.Get(KeyNames.EncodedKey).ToString()
```

Where `KeyNames` is an enum.

I can't use `HttpContext`. What should I check before I just use `KeyNames.EncodedKey` instead of `HttpContext.Current.Application.Get(KeyNames.EncodedKey).ToString()` ? (or is there another way?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store data in the `Application` object, just like you can store stuff in the `Session` or in the `ViewState`. This data is stored in a dictionary-like data structure, so you have a *key* as well as a *value*.

Now, the two things you mentioned are two fundamentally different things:

- `KeyNames.EncodedKey` is just an enum value.
- `HttpContext.Current.Application.Get(KeyNames.EncodedKey).ToString()` returns the *value* stored in the Application object whose *key* is `KeyNames.EncodedKey`. The *value* is then converted to a string.

So, just using `KeyNames.EncodedKey` is in no way a replacement for `HttpContext...etc.`.

Just tell us what you want to do and why you cannot use `HttpContext`, then someone might be able to suggest a solution to your problem.